# Two different errors in ubuntu fresh install 15.10 - unity and sysem settings

Tags: unity, 15.10, system-settings

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 15.10 and when I start it up I get an error right away and it asks if I want to report it. It says it is with:

The path - `/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon`

Package - `unity-settings-daemon 15.04.1+15.10.20151021-Oubuntu1`

Problem Type - Crash

ect..

I also get an error when I click on system settings and then go to display. It just crashes and wont give a warning. When I tried it in the terminal and I clicked on it I got the error of:

```
ERROR:gsd-rr-config.c:661:gsd_rr_config_load_current: assertion failed: (gsd_rr_config_match (config, config))
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have ubuntu of the same version on my laptop and never had this much trouble. I'm trying to replace windows but its not looking great for my desktop. My desktop is also a custom build if that helps.